# 'function' object has no attribute '__func__' issue with graphene django

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

```
TypeError: UserProcessOptionsNode fields cannot be resolved. 'function' object has no attribute '__func__'
```

```
class UserProcessOptionsNode(DjangoObjectType):
    client_configuration = GenericScalar()

    class Meta:
        model = api_models.UserProcessOptions
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
        filter_fields = ("user",)

    @classmethod
    def get_queryset(cls, queryset, info):
        user_list = []
        user_list.append(info.context.user)
        user_list.append(info.context.user.parent_user)
        userprocess = queryset.filter(user__in=user_list)
        return userprocess
```

This issue is caused when I upgrade graphene-django from 2.15.0 to 3.1.5.

Comment: I fixed issue by degrading graphene-django to 3.1.3.

Comment: The issue could have to do with your Python version https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods. Are you using Python 3? If not, you should consider upgrading to that and then updating graphene-django.